# How to prevent long tables breaking up using the GoPrettyTable library in Go code?

Tags: go, prettytable

I am learning about the [Go PrettyTable](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jedib0t/go-pretty/v6@v6.4.7/table) library and have come across an issue while trying to print tables with long columns.

If I print a short table, it prints without any issue on the terminal screen. Example:
[image]

But if I try to print a long table with many columns, the output breaks the table and looks like this:
[image]

Is it possible to make the tables horizontally scrollable so that the table could be viewed without it being broken?

For reference, the code that is creating this table can be accessed from [here](https://github.com/TheUncertainOracle/PrettyTables/blob/main/cars.go)

Comment: No, because horizontal scrollability is something of your display/terminal, not some feature of the output.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that, I learnt something new thanks to you! If horizontally scrolling is something that can't be added from the code, would you by any chance know how long tables from my post can be displayed its content breaking up?

Comment: Some output formats like HTML or PDF allow for wide things and viewers of these formats allow scrolling (in both directions). If you need text output there is nothing much you can do except print less columns.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I now understand that tables with many columns cannot be displayed in the terminal without breaking and that there are other alternatives that can be followed instead. 

I am really sorry for asking this question and thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is that a 'horizontally scrollable' wide table is not possible by modifying the program code.

Alternatively, you will have to:
-- reduce the number of columns that are to be displayed
-- you can reduce the terminal size to view the unbroken table
-- save the output as pdf or other formats

Special thanks to @Volker for helping me understand this!